# Find the default terminal emulator

Tags: linux, terminal, desktop

How would one detect which terminal emulator (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`...) is used in the current desktop environment ? Like `xdg-open`, but for the terminal emulator.

I already tried the `xdg-terminal` script on my Xubuntu installation, with no luck :

```
./xdg-terminal.sh: 305: [: x: unexpected operator
./xdg-terminal.sh: 399: [: xxterm: unexpected operator
xdg-terminal: configured terminal program 'xterm' not found or not executable
```

It would be for using in a C++ program, so any script, package or built-in command will do.

Comment: Are you running that script with the correct shell?  Those seem like the sort of errors I'd expect if you were using a different shell from the one in which the script was written or something like that

Comment: Do you really need to be able to _identify_ which terminal emulator is the default? Or just launch it?

Comment: I just need to launch it

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu it's `x-terminal-emulator`. I don't know if it's generic across distros or not.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up using `xterm`

Answer (score 6):

### Short answer

There is no standard for knowing what the default terminal emulators is across distros. In fact, the user might use 'by default' a completely different terminal than the one that ships with the desktop environment. You would only be able to guess it by looking into different system variables and config files.

### Longer answer

You can try to guess your way forward with `$TERM`

Please refer to `man term.5` and/or `man term.7` (pages 5 and 7 of the term manual page).

> The environment variable TERM should normally contain the type name of the terminal, console or display-device type you are using. This information is critical for all screen-oriented programs, including your editor and mailer.
>
> A default TERM value will be set on a per-line basis by either /etc/inittab (Linux and System-V-like UNIXes) or /etc/ttys (BSD UNIXes). This will nearly always suffice for workstation and microcomputer consoles.

On my Manjaro i3 install

```
$ echo $TERM
rxvt-unicode-256color
```

which is the other name for `urxvt`. So you can't even expect to get the right name of the default terminal.

As detailed [in this reply](https://superuser.com/a/361661/1011350)

> If your $TERM has [something you don't recognise], carefully check your configuration, including:
>
> - the agetty lines in /etc/inittab (they should say linux at the end1)
>
>   - system-wide shell startup scripts
>
>     - /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/*.sh
>     - /etc/bash.bashrc (if using bash)
>   - your own shell startup scripts
>
>     - ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.bashrc

### Advice : just go through a list of known terminal emulators

By default i3 comes with `i3-sensible-terminal`. According to it's manual

> i3-sensible-terminal is invoked in the i3 default config to
>   start a terminal. This wrapper script is necessary since there
>   is no distribution-independent terminal launcher (but for
>   example Debian has x-terminal-emulator). Distribution packagers
>   are responsible for shipping this script in a way which is
>   appropriate for the distribution.

And the way it works is just by going through the list of commonly used terminal emulators

> It tries to start one of the following (in that order):
>
> - $TERMINAL (this is a non-standard variable)
> - x-terminal-emulator (only present on Debian and derivatives)
> - urxvt
> - rxvt
> - termit
> - terminator
> - ...

Where

- `$TERMINAL` is usually set in the aforementioned startup scripts when it is used.
- `x-terminal-emulator` is the Debian way of asking for the default terminal (works on Ubuntu)

In a bash script, that would give something along the lines of

```bsh
terms=(emulator1 emulator2 emulator3)
for t in ${terms[*]}
do
    if [ $(command -v $t) ]
    then
        detected_term=$t
        break
    fi
done
echo $detected_term
```